# How to add class argument on frame object tkinder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I want to load several frame object here : Matwin
With the data of my object : material
I have tried to add material as argument to my Matwin object here mat but it's not working...

Here there is my code :

```
class Matwin(PanedWindow):
 def __init__(self,parent,mat):
     PanedWindow.__init__(self,parent,mat)
     self.pack()
     self.parent= parent

     self.bouton=Button(self, text=mat.path, padx=10,pady=10,command=mat.command)
     self.bouton.pack()

     self.label = Label(self, text=mat.nom)
     self.label.pack()
class Material:
 def __init__(self,name):
      self.name = name
      self.path = "Picture path"

 def command(self):
      print("this is the ",self.name," command")  
win = Tk()
aobj = Material("a")
bobj = Material("b")
cobj = Material("c")
listobj =[aobj,bobj,cobj]
i = 0
while i < len(listobj):
 test = Matwin(win,listobj[i])
```

I have TypeError: argument of type 'Material' is not iterable
Maybe it's not the good way to do thaht can you help me ?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?  The only real thing i see that involves iterables would be your while loop, which does not have an incrementor.  Im not sure what the panedWindow class is doing with Mat though. Not sure the use case of your code, but maybe you could try:

`for mat in listobj: test = Matwin(win,mat)`

Comment: yes i forget to copy the last line i +=1,so it also doesn't work with for mat in listobj: test = Matwin(win,mat)

Comment: a stack trace or more information might help